# alertDialog accessing value inside onClick()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

how to access value accepted from user in onClick() outside the onClick(). I have declared the variable currentIntervalchoice globally in which I am retriving the value. how to access the value of currentIntervalchoice in else{} part.

```
    private void doFirstRun()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true))
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in 1st run true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
            {
                 String value = userInput.getText().toString();
                 currentIntervalChoice=Integer.parseInt(value);
                toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                        AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this,currentIntervalChoice));
                dialog.dismiss();
                // return;  
            }
              });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in 1st run false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
        toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this,currentIntervalChoice));
    }
```

Comment: Where is currentIntervalChoice defined?

Comment: oops.sory I ll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you're using shared preferences to store/check whether this is the first run of the app.  Your `else` part will not be executed on the same run (because it's either first run or not).  What you should do instead is store the value entered by the user into the shared preferences, exactly the same way as you're storing the `isFirstRun` flag.  Then in your `else` part, simply read that value from your shared preferences.  Something like this:

```
final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true))
{
    ...

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
        {
             String value = userInput.getText().toString();
             int currentIntervalChoice=Integer.parseInt(value);
             Editor edit = settings.edit();
             editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
             editor.putInt("currentIntervalChoice", currentIntervalChoice);
             editor.commit();

             ...
        }
          });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
else
{
    int currentIntervalChoice = settings.getInt("currentIntervalChoice", 0);

    ...
}
```

Note that I removed unrelated code - you'll probably need to keep it. I also moved storing your `isFirstRun` flag inside the `onClick`. You may also want to add some validation on this value, but it's down to your logic.